# How does contain function work in xpath

Tags: xpath, contains

```
<collection>
<movie title="Transformers" shelf="B">
   <type>Science Fiction</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>1980</year>
   <rating>R</rating>
   <popularity>7</popularity>
   <description>Science Fiction</description>
</movie>
   <movie title="Trigun" shelf="B">
   <type>Action</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <episodes>4</episodes>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <popularity>10</popularity>
   <description>Quite a bit of action!</description>
</movie>
<movie title="Ishtar" shelf="A">
   <type>Comedy</type>
   <format>VHS</format>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <popularity>2</popularity>
   <description>Boring</description>
</movie>
</collection>
```

In the above code segment,I want to get the title attribute for the segment where the description element contains a sub-string function.I tried to use contains functions which returns Boolean and expects a string for the argument. I tried something few Xpaths but dint work and got to know the answer is **collection/movie[contains(description,'bit')]/@title**

Since contains returns only Boolean value, how does it work in the above case.Please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with `contains()` specifically, `[...]` simply defines a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-predicates), with which to filter things. So `tag[boolean-expression()]` will return to you exactly those `tag`s for which `boolean-expression()` returns `true()` (or to be more precise: [a value that can be converted to `true()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-ebv)).